# Add single doskey command - Windows Registry

Tags: batch-file, registry, doskey

I'm working on a batch file, and I need to add this entry:

```
doskey wfreerdp="C:\Program Files\wfreerdp\wfreerdp.exe" $*
```

to this regkey:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

I played with the options of `reg add`, but I simply cannot get it to work.

I know it should be something like:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v doskey wfreerdp = "C:\Program Files\wfreerdp\wfreerdp.exe" $*
```

but I don't which one and how to use the `/t`, `/S`, `/d` & `/f` flags.

If I manually add the entry:

```
doskey wfreerdp = "C:\Program Files\wfreerdp\wfreerdp.exe" $*
```

it works perfectly.

Alternativelly I tried creating the `C:\bat\macros.doskey` file, containing the doskey command:

```
doskey wfreerdp = "C:\Program Files\wfreerdp\wfreerdp.exe" $*
```

and the following in the batch file:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v Autorun /d "doskey /macrofile=\"c:\bat\macros.doskey\"" /f
```

No success.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to add the `doskey` command to your Command Prompt's AutoRun so that it will run every time you open `cmd.exe`, then you would need to run the following:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v "AutoRun" /d "doskey wfreerdp = \"C:\Program Files\wfreerdp\wfreerdp.exe\" $*"
```

Let's break this down:

- From the documentation at `cmd /?`:

  > ```
  > If /D was NOT specified on the command line, then when CMD.EXE starts, it
  > looks for the following REG_SZ/REG_EXPAND_SZ registry variables, and if
  > either or both are present, they are executed first.
  >
  >     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
  >
  >         and/or
  >
  >     HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
  > ```
- You already know you're placing the key into `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`.
- The `/v` switch specifies the value name to add/modify, which in this case is the `AutoRun` key.
- The `/d` switch specifies what that key should contain, which in this case is the `doskey` command.
- Since your command contains quotation marks (`"`), you would need to escape them so they are not processed by the command line (`\"`).